# Regex excluding a charachter from the end of a group

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am trying to parse a syslog line:

```
pam_vas: Authentication <succeeded> for <active directory> user: <bobtheperson> account: <bobtheperson@com.com> reason: <N/A> Access cont(upn): <bob>
```

My goal is to break this data into key/value pairs. It needs to be perl regex (this happens to be going into Splunk for solaris logs, in case someone was curious what it was for).

So far, i have this:

```
[\>\:]*\s+(.*?)\<(.+?)\>
```

It does a good job extracting my data, but anywhere a word ends in a colon, it is included in group one.

Expected result:

```
Authentication = succeeded
for = active directory
user = bobtheperson
account = bobtheperson@com.com
reason = N/A
Access cont(upn) = bob
```

Actual result (Note the colons)

```
Authentication = succeeded
for = active directory
user: = bobtheperson
account: = bobtheperson@com.com
reason: = N/A
Access cont(upn): = bob
```

The link to http://regexr.com/ code:
http://regexr.com/3fasr
A lot of trial and error got me to this spot -- i just cant figure out how to take out that last piece of punctuation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex seems to work out for you:

```
[\>\:]*\s+(.*?)\:?\s\<(.+?)\>
```

As you can see here:
http://regexr.com/3fatg

ior

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/kytsYDvJdaXsmNP5)

Comment: Awesome! I almost had it, it seems like.
Thank you for the quick reply.